# Class Name and File Name

Tags: python, class, filenames

I am from Java background. I am going through the official Python tutorials but can't seem to find the information in relation to Python source file names and classes.

In Java, file name is the same as main class name plus the .java extension. In Python what's the case? In the examples of official tutorials, they are writing multiple classes and there's no mention of the file name. I am kind of lost.

I have a file name called test_pie.py. The content is-

```
class ListTest:

    list1 = [2, 'a', 'ab', 'c', 'aa', 0]

    list2 = ['b', list1[-2:-5]] 

    def PrintList(self):
        print list1
        print list2
```

For list1 and list2: I get-

Undefined variable: list1
list Found at: test_pie

Undefined variable: list2
list Found at: test_pie

Comment: You seem to have multiple questions here. Which one do you want answered?

Comment: I put the code snippet as I was thinking this caused by the file name and class name discrepancies. After editing, I saw your answer (It was fast). I liked your answer. This was clear.

Comment: The code snippet has nothing to do with any of the question before it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a file. Period. Whatever is contained in it is of no interest for imports, and the file name or location doesn't have any effect on the contained code (generally - it *is* accessible during execution, so some metaprogramming makes use of it but should be agnostic w.r.t. the actual value).

The contents of a file are *not* restricted to a single class, and few people impose such a restriction onto themselves. Python isn't exclusively an OO language, you can and should have free functions whenever it's sensible, and modules are seen one level above classes in code organizations - if several classes are closely related, they should propably go in one module.

Your example code/problem is unrelated to this, it's a matter of scoping inside a given file. Classes do have their own scope, but you can't and shouldn't be using the class variables of the containing class in methods like this (directly) - it would make the code oblivious to a new value set in a subclass. Instead, you either use class methods (by the way, you should propably read http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) or make use of the fact that instances inherit all members of the class and just prefix it with `self.`.

Comment: Instances don't "inherit" attributes (the Pythonic name for "members") of the class; rather, attempting to look up an attribute in an object will also try looking in the class if the object doesn't have one. This means that if `list1` is used in this manner, it will effectively be **shared** between instances of the class. Beware.

Comment: @Karl: Yes, that's of course what I meant but failed to express properly. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 12):

In Python a single file constitutes a *module*, which is similar to a namespace in Java, so you would have all the classes for a single namespace in the same file.

Comment: I triggered a backflash on it... when I found that what I thought to be a class turned out to be just a module. The world of Python goes again the best programming practice... :(

Answer (score 9):

Java is not Python. Python is not Java. There are **many** differences that you just uncovered here; more than you'd expect.

> In Java, file name is the same as main class name plus the .java extension. In Python what's the case?

The opposite: the file name is not necessarily the same as anything.

> In the examples of official tutorials, they are writing multiple classes and there's no mention of the file name. I am kind of lost.

Because it doesn't matter. (Note that in Java you can still have more than one class per file as long as only one, with the corresponding name, is `public`. In Python, `public` doesn't really exist as such.)

> For list1 and list2: I get-
>
> Undefined variable: list1 list Found at: test_pie
>
> Undefined variable: list2 list Found at: test_pie

This is because those attributes (what you would call "fields" in Java) belong to the class, not the object.

The method (same name as Java) still "belongs to" the class, in Python-think, but it's accessed via an object. That's why you need an explicit `self` parameter for Python methods: because `my_object.do_something(x, y, z)` is implicitly translated into `MyClass.do_something(my_object, x, y, z)` (more or less; there is some trickery behind the scenes with "binding", which allows you to treat `my_object.do_something` as an object. Yes, in Python, everything is an object, even **functions**. And you thought Java was OO. Hah.)

You can still access the class attributes via an object, if you tell Python where to look for it. Within `PrintList`, `list1` and `list2` are **not** in scope - because Python really only has two scopes: local and global. But `self` is in scope (it's a parameter, so it's in the local scope), and you can access `self.list1`, since looking up an attribute on an object in Python falls back to the class attributes if there isn't an object attribute. (Actually, it's more complicated than that; there are a couple different special-method-name hooks you can insert into the process, to say nothing of how inheritance is dealt with.)

So you're probably wondering by now just how you get attributes into an actual Python object instead of its class. The answer: you just assign them. If you don't place any restrictions, then you can assign them at any time, with any name. The object is basically just a dictionary. If you're familiar with Java**script** (a language completely unrelated to Java), then it works rather the same way. However, to control the madness, it is normal to assign starting attribute values in a specially-named method `__init__`, which is automatically called (if found) immediately upon the creation of the object (but it is **not** a constructor in the usual sense; that role is played by `__new__`, but you almost never actually need that in Python), and then only re-assign to attributes that were set there rather than creating new ones.

You can set restrictions, if you have a new-style class (automatic in 3.x; in 2.x you must inherit at least indirectly from the built-in type `object`), by specifying a value for a specially-named class attribute called `__slots__`. This should be a list of strings that are valid identifier names. With this in place, Python will (a) use the information to optimize its internal storage of data for the objects; (b) disallow you from adding attributes with other names to the object; (c) suppress the creation of the special `__dict__` attribute for object instances which is a dictionary mapping attribute names to attribute values. (And you thought Java supported reflection. Hah.) It will **not** automatically assign any values for the named attributes; attempting to access them before they've been assigned will `raise AttributeError`.